# Arduino PWM MOSFET LED strip driver

Tags: arduino, mosfet, led, pwm, rgb

First off, my electronics knowledge is really basic. I learned some at school and very simple projects with Arduino. I'm a scale modeler making a specific diorama with LED lighting.

I'm trying to design an Arduino Mega shield that will allow me to turn on and off six 12v RGB LED strips fading in and fading out. After some research, I found that the best way to do so was to use N-channel MOSFETs as switches, instead of Darlington transistors, due to heat issues.
The current taken by each strip is between 100mA and 400mA.

Also, I might be interested in varying the color in each LED strip, depending on the need.

I came out with this circuit (x6), where D2 is an Arduino pin sending the PWM signal, SV1 is the connector to the LED strip and the potentiometers are intended for color adjusting. I used 2SK3918 MOSFETs (I know they are not logic level and I can change them for logic level ones). R1 is the pull-down resistor to ensure 0V at the MOSFET when initializing. I've read somewhere that there's a need for a Gate resistor, but somewhere else I read it's not needed.

[image]

I made a prototype board, connected it outside the arduino but couldn't make it work.

[image]
[image]

I connect 12v and GND to X1. 0-5v (testing up to 20v) power supply to D2 and GND and a test LED strip to the corresponding terminals at SV1.

No matter what voltage is applied to D2, the LED strip is continuously on. There's 12v all the time at each pin in SV1.

I know I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Why didn't you simulate first? Why are both power rails at GND?

Comment: I didn't simulate first because I didn't have any of the parts and it was cheaper to make the prototypes than buying the components for simulation.
About both power rails at GND... I don't know. Probably I saw somewhere that was a good idea. Is it preferably one at GND and the other at 12v?

Comment: By "simulation" we mean on a computer with something like LTSpice or Falstad: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html

Comment: OH! I didn't know about those tools. I only knew Pspice which was paid software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've connected the top side of the potentiometers to GND, and the bottom side of the potentiometers to the MOSFETs, which then also connect through to ground.

When you plug the lighting strips in, there's a path from the 12V supply (pin 1 of SV1) through the lighting strips, back through SV1, through the potentiometers, and back to ground *regardless* of whether your MOSFETs are on or off.

It isn't clear what those potentiometers were supposed to do. You should remove them and just have the lines from the LED strips going straight back into the drain pins of the MOSFETs.

> I used 2SK3918 MOSFETs (I know they are not logic level and I can change them for logic level ones).

If you're using 5V logic levels, the 2SK3918 is fine. You're way above its Vgs(th) at 5V and you can see from the forward transfer characteristics graph in the datasheet that the forward current (Id)  is more than 10A at a Vgs of 5V.

That said, these MOSFETs are *massive* overkill for your design and I would recommend using smaller ones in future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Well, each 4 pin connector should drive one independent strip. Each strip will be lit in a different color. I thought about pots as a way to change colors in the strips, but not mandatory.
I'll try removing the pots.

Comment: Technically you would've had the right idea there you hadn't connected pin 3 of the potentiometers to ground. However, you'd be dissipating a lot of power in the potentiometers (at 400mA the pots would dissipate several watts, which would quickly turn them to molten slag) so it's not really the correct approach. If you used separate PWM signals for each MOSFET, you could independently control the channels.

Comment: For now, if you desolder the pots and bridge pin 2 to pin 1 on the PCB, leaving pin 3 disconnected, that should get your circuit up and working.

Comment: Yes, I wondered they were too much, but I thought smaller ones like SOT-23 wouldn't be able to take the current (I need to understand the datasheets better :) )

Comment: Will try that. Thanks!!!

Comment: For MOSFETs, look in the datasheet for a graph called "forward transfer characteristics" that plots _Vgs_ (gate-source voltage) on the X axis and _Id_ (drain current) on the Y axis. Vgs is the voltage between the gate and source pins of the MOSFET. Since the source pin is usually connected to ground, Vgs is usually equal to your gate drive voltage from your microcontroller or whatever. That graph will tell you how much current the MOSFET will conduct at any particular Vgs.

Comment: The gate threshold voltage, Vgs(th), is also a useful indicator for what gate voltages are likely to be suitable, but keep in mind that the Vgs(th) just tells you when the MOSFET _starts_ conducting, not when it can conduct a significant amount of current, so always check the graph in the datasheet. Also try not to use MOSFETs at a gate voltage lower than what they specify an on-resistance, aka Rds(on), for. If you look at the table in the datasheet you'll usually see Rds(on) values specified for e.g. Vgs=4.5V, Vgs=10V, etc. and the smallest Vgs number there is the lowest you should go ideally

Comment: The other thing to check is the Vgs vs. Rds(on) graph, which tells you what the effective resistance of the MOSFET is at a given gate voltage. So on the 2SK3918 for example it's about 5.8mΩ at a gate voltage of 10V, or 12mΩ at a gate voltage of 5V. Then you can plug that resistance and your device current into P=I²R to get the power dissipation in the MOSFET. So in your case it's Rds(on) = 0.012Ω, and 0.4A, so 0.4² x 0.012 = 1.9mW dissipated, which is tiny and no problem. But let's say you wanted to use 10A strips, that'd be 10² x 0.012 = 1.2W, which means the MOSFETs would get _very_ hot.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
I've tried removing the potentiometers, but still have the same issue. The LED strip is still on all the time regardless the voltage at the gate.

I was wondering... in the schematics, the Source is grounded and the Drain is where the load is connected to. In the datasheet, the drain is the thermal pad (not sure about how to call it), but in the PCB, no matter what EDA I use, it's always the other way around. Is it correct? or am I missing something there?

Comment: @PSedney TO-252 packages _technically_ have four pins: three on the south side, plus the fin on the north side. The center pin on the south side is usually a stub, and by convention is internally bonded to the fin. In the case of the 2SK3918, the fin is the drain pin. I checked the EasyEDA part entry for the 2SK3918 and it is wrong, as you noted. It looks like someone created the schematic symbol with the correct pin numbers (1=G, 2=D, 3=S) but then assigned a standard TO-252 package footprint where the pin numbers _skipped_ the center pin, making the left pin 1, the right 2, and the fin 3.

Comment: @PSedney If you're using EasyEDA, search for 2SK3918-ZK. I've added an updated component to the user libraries that has the correct TO-252 footprint pinout. Unfortunately this does mean that your existing PCB is incorrect and you'll have to get new ones made. Don't worry, though, this is all part of the learning process - always check that part symbols and footprints supplied with EDAs or contributed by other users are correct and match the datasheet, and if they don't match then you should assume that the datasheet is correct and someone else messed up.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought... Funny thing is that one night I suddently woke up to the thought of that being wrong, checked other photos and saw the fin connected to ground, so I said... "ok, we'll see when it comes".
Luckily, the PCB weren't expensive, so I can take it as the learning process, as you say.
Thank you very much for your help, @Polynomial. I'll have new boards made and will feedback to you.
Cheers!

Comment: hi! Finally the new boards arrived. I tested them and work perfectly. In this new version, I removed tge potentiometers and added gate resistors. Thanks for your help and comments. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it works! :)